# Run program for 3 seconds

Tags: c, linux, time

I'm trying to run a small piece of code for 3 seconds:
Example:

```
WHILE(3 SECONDS){
  printf("Hey");
}
```

I've tried to use time_t, counting some time till I reach a limit, like this:

```
time_t endwait;
time_t atual = (unsigned int)time(NULL);
time_t duration = secs;

while(atual < endwait){
  printf("Hey");
}
```

But it's not working, the program is stuck in a loop printing "Hey".

Comment: You probably want to set actual again inside the loop ? It's always going to be true because the variables never change

Comment: Initializing `endwait` would be a great idea too.

Comment: where do you set what endwait is equal to? it appears you just check if the current time is less than whatever value was in endwait when it was declared since you never actually give it value, so the while loop would probably be undefined behavior that just happens to loop forever because of whatever endwait starts as

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short version:

```
time_t endwait = time(NULL) + secs;

while(time(NULL) < endwait){
  printf("Hey");
}
```

Or even:

```
for(time_t start = time(NULL);time(NULL)-start < secs;) printf("Hey");
```

Comment: I'm willing to bet that this will keep on printing `Hey`s long after the timer has ended. `printf` is actually a very bad function to test this with. (I also bet you knew already this.)

Answer (score 3):

You need to retrieve the current time within the while loop. So, taking your code, it should look something like this:

```
time_t actual = time(NULL);
time_t duration = secs;
time_t endwait = actual + duration ;

while(actual < endwait){
  printf("Hey");
  actual = time(NULL);
}
```

Comment: You don't need to cast `time(NULL)` since it returns a `time_t` type value.